# My harddisk is facing problems

Tags: hardware, filesystem

How do I image the disk and copy it to new disk to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu and Windows 8.

Are there any special steps; since I am dealing with a dual boot windows 8 and I am replacing one of two hard drives?

How do I fix corrupt partition tables and MBR code. In AMD-64 assembly language with comments what should this code read so I can do a compare? I know every hard drive has proprietary firmware on it. But if I can learn to fix this kind of hard drive problem it would interesting. Most hard drives are reported as failures after multiple repartitions and MBR becomes corrupt without actual hardware part failure. I don't want to spend the money on shipping a hard drive if can learn to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving the cloning is to use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).
One way to fix the corrupt partition tables and MBR code is to use [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/).
One way to check the health of your drive is to use software from manufacturers website. i.e. [Seatools](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/seatools/)

I have started using [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php#.Uad3ABUjulM) live cd for partitioning and rescue cd as it has many useful tools and apps including Clonezilla and FixParts and other tools to check and test the health of hard drives.